# Django View function. Can't get a value from Dictionary, only full dictionary

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I want to get a value from a dictionary which I get from request session

`words = request.session['words']`

In the Python console I get my expected result:

`>>> words 
{0: "value_0", 1: "value_1", 2: "value_2", 3: "value_3", 4: "value_4"}`

`>>> words[0]
'value_0'`

I have a variable called `wordcount = 0` and  get the result exactly as expected, whatever else.

`>>> words[wordcount]
'value_0'`

But, If I try to get a value in my Django view function, it doesn't work

Here are my two view functions:

```
def first_view(request):
    words = {}
    wordcount = 0
    request.session['wordcount'] = wordcount
    for i in range(5):
        words[i] = "value_" + str(i)
    request.session['words'] = words

def second_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        message = "checkpoint_1"
        words = request.session['words']
        wordcount = request.session['wordcount']
        if request.POST.get("input"):
            input = request.POST.get("input").upper()
            message = words[wordcount]
            data = {'message': message}
            return JsonResponse(data)
```

The second view is called by an Ajax-Request

```
$(button).on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var input = $('#input').val();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/second_view/",
        data: { "input": input },
        dataType: "json",
        context: this,
        success: function (data) {
           output.innerHTML = data.message;
        }
    });
});
```

My expectation is, that the Response `data.message` is `'value_1'`, but I get the `'checkpoint_1'` message. If I replace the following part:

```
if request.POST.get("input"):
        input = request.POST.get("input").upper()
        message = words
        data = {'message': message}
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

I get the response message: `{0: "value_0", 1: "value_1", 2: "value_2", 3: "value_3", 4: "value_4"}`

why the hell I'm not getting what I expect: `words[wordcount] -> 'value_0'` equal result to `words[0]`

Comment: Is that your actual code? I don't see why you expect to get `'value_1'`. What is the point of `input = request.POST.get("input").upper()` if you never use `input`? If the view is returning `checkpoint_1`, that suggests that the view never enters the `if request.POST.get("input"):` block. You should add some more printing/logging to see whether that's the case.

Comment: The view is already returning `message = words` but not `message = words[0]`because the keys are integer. If I change the keys to strings, my code works fine as expected.

Comment: Note that json only allows strings as keys, so if you are using the default json serializer for the session, then `{0: "value_0", 1: "value_1", 2: "value_2", 3: "value_3", 4: "value_4"}` will be converted to `{"0": "value_0", "1": "value_1", "2": "value_2", "3": "value_3", "4": "value_4"}` when you retrieve it from the session.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was surprised that I did not get the value within a python script. This should not really have anything to do with the Json Response, right? Now I have formatted the keys as a string and it works.

Comment: No, this is unrelated to the JSON response. The conversion happens when your dictionary gets stored in the session.

Comment: Okay, that's logical. Good to know what exactly the problem is. Many Thanks. I have previously only thought about the JsonResponse, but the problem is here at the session storage.